# Passing URL (GET) var to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, url

I'm playing With wordpress, loading content into my theme from a custom page. What I have is:

header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#another").click(function(){
   $("#randomPost")
            .text("... loading ...")
            .load("/wp/ajax-page/?id=<? echo $id; ?>+cachebuster=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
   return false;
});
</script>
```

index.php

```
<a href="#?id=1" id="another">Get another!</a>
```

ajax_page.php (http://localhost/wp/ajax-page/)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: AJAX
*/
?>

<?
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<?php 
    query_posts('showposts=1&id='.$id.''); 
    the_post();
?>

<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Everything works fine, it's the simpler way that i've found to load data into a div under wordpress (with javascript). My problem is that i can't get to pass the id Var through the URL, any ideas?

Thanks so much guys, I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#another").click(function(){
   $("#randomPost")
            .text("... loading ...")
            .load("/wp/ajax-page/?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&cachebuster=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
   return false;
});
</script>
```

The problem was... on the load. You were printing the $id but you forgot tu add the & so you send the id parameter and the cachebuster parameter. They were together.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$("#another").click(function(){
   $("#randomPost")
            .text("... loading ...")
            .load("/wp/ajax-page/?cachebuster=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
   return false;
});
</script>
This works fine!

Comment: I forgot. See this article [link](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html). Using a function to get the GET parameter instead of printing it on the javascript code. There are a lot of similar functions but that was the first link on google =P

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `<? echo $id; ?>` to `document.URL.split('#?id=')[1]`